# Dynamic databinding NodeJS

Tags: node.js, knockout.js

I have a nodeJS application that I have a javascript array of objects. On my jade page I spit them out but now I want to add a filter input that when I type it will start to filter the model that is passed in. Can I do this with Node itself or should I implement something like Knockout JS to create observable arrays? If so does someone have a link to a tutorial to use KO with NodeJS?

JS Array Object

```
var sections = [
    {
        title: 'Verity Monitoring',
        links: [
            {
                name: 'Verity ',
                link: '#'
            },
            {
                name: 'Hits',
                link: '#'
            },
            {
                name: 'Verity Hits Line Chart with Ratios',
                link: '#'
            },
            {
                name: 'Verity Cache Performance',
                link: '#'
            },
            {
                name: 'Verity Usage for a Date ',
                link: '#'
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'Solr Monitoring',
        links: [
            {
                name: 'Solr Requests',
                link: '#'
            },
            {
                name: 'Solr Errors Stores',
                link: '#'
            },
            {
                name: 'Solr Timeouts',
                link: '#'
            },
            {
                name: 'Solr Average Response Time',
                link: '#'
            }
        ]
    }
];

exports.sections = sections;
```

Comment: I would think this is something that could be handled entirely client-side, unless you're mean you're updating the backing data set in the background via socket.io or something...

Comment: For now it could be client side because it loading the data from a file. I may want to switch this out to a mongodb or some api call

Comment: In that case it will probably depend on whatever autocomplete library you end up using client-side, as far as what is expected server-side for filtering purposes.

Comment: I just went ahead and moved the object to the client side and just doing it that way